# jQuery Hide Class with Slide Transition

Tags: jquery, transition

I'm trying to collapse a vertical left bar with a slide transition.  I start with a larger width (250px), down to a smaller width (50px) toolbar size.

I can hide/show the wide bar completely with a nice slide transition using:

```
$("#pnlLeftSide").hide('slide', {direction:'left'}, 300);
$("#pnlLeftSide").show('slide', {direction:'left'}, 300);
```

Or I can add a class to go from wide to mini, which basically hides a lot of inner content and then displays a few smaller toolbar type things using:

```
$("#pnlLeftSide").toggleClass("min");
```

But I can't go from wide to mini, with a nice smooth slide transition as it collapses in size (width).

If I try this, it jerks at the end as it changes visibility:

```
if ($("#pnlLeftSide").hasClass("min")) {
    $("#pnlLeftSide").show('slide', {direction:'left'}, 300, function() { $(this).removeClass("min"); });
}
else {
    $("#pnlLeftSide").hide('slide', {direction:'left'}, 300, function() { $(this).show().addClass("min"); });
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be helpful to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Why is it $(this).show() at the very end of the hide part?

Comment: The show() is there because I'm trying to slide down to a smaller size, currently using the hide('slide'...), but if I don't include a show() as well it disappears completely, and I still want it to be visible, just a smaller width. It "jerks at the end" with the show() because once it finishes it's slide transition, it essentially pops back from hidden to visible.

Comment: Maybe a better approach than trying to use hide/show('slide'), is instead to use toggleClass("min") with some CSS slide animations. I'm not quite sure how to get that to work, but any help would be appreciated.